# Python Pipe Character for calling functions

Tags: python, pygame, arguments, bitwise-or

just a simple question.

Some python functions I have seen are called like this, for example pygame:

`pygame.display.set_mode((255, 255), FULLSCREEN)` This seems normal to me.

But when you want to use more than one argument, you must use |. For example:
`pygame.display.set_mode((255, 255), FULLSCREEN | HWSURFACE | DOUBLEBUF)`

When and why would you want this kind of calling? I have heard it is the bitwise OR operator, but it seems that is only for boolean values. How does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're flags for different options.  Each flag is just a number, specifically a power of 2.  You use the bitwise operator `|` to flip the bits for all the flags you want.  An example might help:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.VERBOSE
64
>>> re.IGNORECASE
2
>>> re.VERBOSE | re.IGNORECASE
66
```

so if `re` wants to know whether the `IGNORECASE` flag is set it can just check whether the second bit(for 2^1) is equal to 1.  If so, we should ignore case.  And if it wants to know whether to be `VERBOSE`, it checks the 7th bit(for 2^6).  By `or`ing 2 and 64 together, you have a number with the second and seventh bits flipped.

```
>>> 66 & 2
2
>>> 66 & 64
64
>>> 66 & 8
0
```

We can see that 66 triggers flags for 2 and 64, but not 8.

Answer (score 0):

Beware the difference between *bitwise OR* operator with the *boolean OR* operator:

`|` is the bitwise OR operator, that is, the OR operation is made bit per bit of the operands:

```
>>> 1 | 2
3
```

That's because 1 binary is `001`, 2 binary is `010`, so the OR bit per bit of them is `011`, that is, 3.

`or` is the boolean operator.

```
>>> 1 or 2
1
>>> 0 or 2
2
```

The `or` operator returns the first valid value (not  `0`, `None`, `[]` or `{}`)

Comment: May I ask, where can I get a table of binary numbers (001 = 1)?

Comment: more specifically, the section "Counting in binary"